# Templating in Kohana Framework 3.3

Tags: templates, frameworks, kohana

I'm using Kohana Framework and this is actually the first framework that I am using. I just wanted to know how to properly add templates in views. What I am doing right now is.

In controller.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'site';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->header = View::factory('templates/header');
        $this->template->header->title = 'Page name - Welcome';
        $this->template->header->description = 'Blah blah blah.';
    }
```

Now inside view I make a file called site.php (the view) and echo the variable $header on the top so it shows the contents of the page, and it's working fine but is it actually the right way to do it? I mean echoing out the header in every single view? I'm sure there must be a more complex or better way to do that. I have also heard that the use of Kohana Templete is discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com) Plugin **[KOstache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/)** for Kohana. IMO the best way to separate your layout from your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kostache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/)
It allows you to do simple things like

```
<li>{{kostachevariable}}</li>
```

You just create the view extending Kostache class and that's it. 
Once you do that you can just set variables using

```
$pagetitle="My Title"
$myview-bind('mypagetitle',$pagetitle)
```

In your template file you will only need

```
<head>
<title>{{mypagetitle}}</title>
```

It has tons of other nice features.